# Why Migi could replace the heart but not the brain?

Tags: parasyte

In the Keisejuu anime, Migi says he can't replace the brain anymore because he grew outside of it and it's already late. But later when Shinichi is about to die, he replaces his heart and fixs it, and later it tells 30% of him remained in the heart and other parts of the body. Why he could replace the heart but not the brain?

Comment: As I understood it, these parasites can only grow to replace the brain during the first couple seconds of invading a body. After that their own brain develops and is no longer capable of invading the host's brain. Migi is kind of a unique example of his species, so by the time he got very smart, he probably figured out how to become a muscle (since a heart is just a muscle) to replace/fix/aid Shinichi's heart.

Comment: @Hakase Please use answers to answer a question instead of comments. Comments are primarily for suggesting improvements

Comment: @Jesse I expected someone else to post a more comprehensive answer than what I've got in my comment. Feel free to remix the info I've posted so far however you like in your own answer